# Vue.js component image blank

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, src

I've bound a computed property to the `src` of an image tag in Vue.js. The code appears to correct, but does not work consistently which is baffling to me. Additionally, switching to the `/about` page and back to the main books page always properly displays the images.

Any information as to what could be causing this issue would be wonderful!

A hosted version of the app is available here: https://books.surge.sh/

[The relevant code for the book-item component.](https://github.com/robertbenjamin/books/blob/master/src/components/BookItem.vue)

[The full Github repo.](https://github.com/robertbenjamin/books)

The code generating the book component and image `src` is as follows:

```
<template>
  <article class="book-item">
    <img :src="imgSrc" class="image">
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="name">{{ book.title }}</div>*
      <div class="author">{{ book.author }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p v-html="book.description"></p>
    </div>
  </article>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['book'],
  computed: {
    imgSrc() {
      return `/static/img/${this.book.image}`;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Partially displayed book covers on initial load:

[image: Partially displayed images.]

Comment: Seems like an issue with your CSS because if you open up chrome devtools and inspect the element you can always see the src tag and it links properly. When I simply set your `img` to `display: block` it already triggers and renders it.

Comment: *Update: Any layout change in any element will cause it to render as long as the content is repainted in any way. This might be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with .image `'width'` style. You should assign that .image class after your component renders. Do this:

```html
<template>
  <article class="book-item">
    <img :src="imgSrc" :class="{image: componentLoaded}"> <!-- 1. change class -->
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="name">{{ book.title }}</div>*
      <div class="author">{{ book.author }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p v-html="book.description"></p>
    </div>
  </article>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['book'],
  data() {
    return {
      componentLoaded: false           // 2. add this 'state' data
    };
  },
  computed: {
    imgSrc() {
      return `/static/img/${this.book.image}`;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // 3. This will assign class to your image
    // after component did mounted (nextTick() did not helped)
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.componentLoaded = true;
    }, 1);
  }
};
</script>
```

Good luck !
I created a pull request [here](https://github.com/robertbenjamin/books/pull/1)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I found out a way to get it working with just CSS changes, but it was super helpful to realize that the issue was related to the image's height / width CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephan-v pointed out, the issue was with the `img` height and width CSS properties. The .image class had been set to `width: 150px; height: 100%;` but since the image src isn't set until Vue's lifecycle hooks complete, the CSS hadn't properly applying until something forced a re-render, such as switching out of the route and back.

I solved this by creating a container `div` around the `img` like so:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img :src="'/static/img/' + image" class="image">
</div>
```

Then setting the container size using `min-height` and `min-width`, with only the child `img` `width` property set to a hard value:

```
> .image-container {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 100%;

  img { width: 150px; }
}
```

Doing so prevents any "dynamic" CSS values (percent width or height rules) from applying to a image with a dynamically set src.